# How to add flat rate shipping for order over X value?

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, table-rates

I would like add a Shopping Cart Price rule that will offer a flat shipping fee if the cart value is over a certain amount.

I've looked at a few tutorials but most seem to offer "Free" shipping and not a flat rate if the cart total equals X amount.

The problem is the flat fee should only apply to items that are added in addition to the main item.For example, if product A is in the cart then B and C will get free shipping but the cost of shipping A will still apply

Comment: Why not just use table shipping rate?

Comment: @Tim why not just write this as an answer? (but a little more detailed)

Comment: @Tim I'm already using Matrix rates but I' not aware of the ability to do this via a shipping method. The problem is the flat fee should only apply to items that are added in addition to the main item.For example, if product A is in the cart then B and C will get free shipping but the cost of shipping A will still apply...

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the following shopping cart rule:

**Condition**:

Order total greater than X

and

Item is found with sku=A

**Action**:

Free shipping

Sku is not A